# Any command line tool for YQL?

Tags: api, command-line

Is there any command line (CLI) implementation for Yahoo Query Language (YQL)?

A substitute for web-based [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)?

Comment: You can do it in your browser, with  http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q={query}
&format={format}

Comment: This is interesting and quite detaield: http://openhacklondon.pbworks.com/f/Yahoo%C2%A0-%C2%A0OHDL%C2%A0-%C2%A0YQL.ppt

Comment: @Mawg Thanks, but web YQL Console is a bit slow for me, as I'm in need to test my own YQL tables and testing it on shell seems to be the fastest way.

Comment: @Mawg Thanks for the link, cURL+PHP example (from the slides) seems to be a good solution. But in example it won't use my custom YQL tables unless I'll published them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found so far Interactive YQL build with Node.js ([GitHub](https://github.com/dgvncsz0f/iyql)) which is based on  old design by Diego Souza (called [iyql package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iyql) at Haskell package archive, see also sources at [GitHub](https://github.com/dgvncsz0f/iyql)).

The old [iyql package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iyql) is similar to popular database frontend interfaces like sqlite3, but this project provides a full featured CLI for YQL.

---

However you don't need any external tool, as you can simply execute YQL queries from the command line using curl, in example:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "www.example.com" AND xpath="//p"' http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql
```

---

I've also created the following simple script ([yql_query.sh](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/scripts/shell/yql_query.sh)):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to execute YQL query via Yahoo API from the command line.
# Usage: ./yql_query.sh query (format) (curl-args)
[ "$1" != "-" ] && query="$1" || query=$(cat -)   # Read query from 1st argument or stdin (-).
format=${2:-xml}                                  # Read format (default to xml).
url_api="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql"
curl -G --data-urlencode "q=$query" "$url_api?format=$format" ${@:3}
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./yql_query.sh 'SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "www.example.com"'
$ echo 'SELECT div FROM html WHERE url = "www.example.com"' | ./yql_query.sh - xml -v
```